# What is the difference between Admob Native Express and Native Advanced Ads

Tags: android

What is the difference between Admob Native Express and Native Advanced Ads?
Are there separate Ad ids for Native express or native advanced ads, i have seen that native advanced use 2 ids , one of Ad id and other is App id but express needs one

Comment: I am afraid that this question is **off-topic** since it is not about programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native Express ads are similar to banners in that they're rectangular ads that you can drop into a layout and size how you like. The key difference is that you, the publisher, can control the ad's presentation details (things like image sizes, fonts, colors, and so on) by uploading a CSS template for your ad unit. AdMob will combine that template with advertiser assets like icons, images, and text, and display the result in a NativeExpressAdView. This approach minimizes the amount of Java code needed for Native Ads Express, while helping publishers display ads that look natural in their app.

Native Ads Advanced is a format in which ad assets are presented to users via UI components that are native to the platform. They're shown using the same types of views with which you're already building your layouts, and can be formatted to match the visual design of the user experience in which they live. In coding terms, this means that when a native ad loads, your app will receive a NativeAd object that contains its assets, and the app (rather than the SDK) is then responsible for displaying them.
There are two system-defined formats for native ads: app install and content. App install ads are represented by `NativeAppInstallAd`, and content ads are represented by `NativeContentAd`. These objects contain the assets for the native ad. You also have the option of defining your own custom native formats, in which case the ads are represented by `NativeCustomTemplateAd`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate more about minimum assets requirements. I mean there are lots of assets available in ads object we can not display all of theme. Is there any document by google which says we must have to display specific assets. (for example Logo, Body and headline are must and rating bar is optional.)

Waiting for your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please share the links to the source article.

Answer (score 0):

Native Ads Advanced is a format in which ad assets are presented to users via UI components that are native to the platform. They're shown using the same types of views with which you're already building your layouts, and can be formatted to match the visual design of the user experience in which they live. In coding terms, this means that when a native ad loads, your app will receive a NativeAd object that contains its assets, and the app (rather than the SDK) is then responsible for displaying them. There are two system-defined formats for native ads: app install and content. App install ads are represented by NativeAppInstallAd, and content ads are represented by NativeContentAd. These objects contain the assets for the native ad.